# Why doesn't the Javadoc for java.util.Scanner describe under what conditions it blocks?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, javadoc

The Javadoc for [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) notes that:

*"Both `hasNext` and `next` methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a `hasNext` method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated `next` method will block."*.

In the descriptions of the various `has*` and `next*` methods, it also notes that they *"may block while waiting for input to scan"*. Nowhere however does the page mention under what conditions these methods may block, in spite of this knowledge being a prerequisite for using them.

My question is hence, why doesn't that Javadoc describe under what conditions a Scanner's methods may block? Is there a legitimate reason for omitting this information, or is it just a case of poor documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've mentioned it, it is pretty vague. Although, explaining it would mean digging into the implementation details.

The `Scanner` mainly relies on the underlying stream. `Scanner#next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` whenever the underlying stream's `read()` method returns `-1` upon reading:

(implementation summary)

```
public void next() {
    if(needInput)
        readInput();
    else
        throwException();
}

void readInput() {
     int n = 0;
     try {
          n = underlyingStream.read(buf);
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
          lastException = ioe;
          n = -1; //error happened
     }

     if (n == -1)
          underlyingStreamClosed = true;
}

void throwException() {
     if (underlyingStreamClosed)
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
     else
          throw new InputMismatchException();
}
```

For example, lets look at `InputStream` without the scanner. `InputStream#read()` blocks when it is called, until data comes in. Using an `InputStream` such as `System.in` will cause your `Scanner` to block, since `InputStream#read()` blocks (the implementation is written in native code, so if you're *really* interested, you can find the file it's located in and look at the implmenetation yourself). This applies to any stream that extends `InputStream`, yet doesn't override `read()` to change it's implementation. For example, `ObjectOutputStream`, `DataOutputStream`

`FileInputStream`, however, does override `read()` (also with a native implmenetation). Calling `FileInputStream#read()` will return `-1` when you attempt to read, yet there is nothing there (although the documentation does say this method may block, I have yet to come across the case). This is purely due to the implementation of `FileInputStream#read()`, which you really shouldn't worry about.

Long story short: It relies on the underlying stream. Become familiar with your streams, and you'll be set. The way I see it, if you're really worried about which stream blocks or not, look at the implementations (I find that when subclasses *don't* override the `read()` method, they tend to block), test them out yourself, or look online. The documentation should likely tell you, although like I said, I have yet to come across a moment when `FileInputStream#read()` has blocked (could someone help me reproduce the situation, if it does as the documentation says?)

Comment: Does this mean that, if reading from System.in, a `NoSuchElementException` will never be thrown, as if stdin is empty then the scanner will always block?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. Please elaborate; "*if reading from System.in, an exception will never be thrown*" confuses me

Comment: That should be 'a NoSuchElementException will never be thrown'. Scanner.next() throws a NoSuchElementException if no more tokens are available, but if it blocks then it means it will wait for a token to be available, and so would not throw a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @LogicChains updated my answer, let me know if you have anymore questions